# How to count rows in tables using subquery SELECT COUNT in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I get error `Subquery returns more than 1 row` when I run this query in MySQL.

```
SELECT a.*,
       (SELECT count(a.ads_id) FROM ads) as ads_count 
FROM ads a
INNER JOIN users u 
ON u.user_id=a.user_id 
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Why the sub-query? `count(a.ads_id)` instead of the sub-query. You are using the alias `a`  inside the subquery.

Comment: count(a.ads_id) will throw the error you get.

Comment: ahh... so that's why it gets error. I remove alias `a` and it works now. thank a lot

Comment: If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns. This causes MySQL to accept the preceding query. In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate, which is probably not what you want. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html